# Which is the equivalent of this JGsoft regular expression in UltraEdit?

Tags: regex, ultraedit

How do I replace the XML expression

```
&apos;
```

with

```
'
```

?

The problem is that the text is divided in multiple formats for the characters:

```
\n   -  10 13
& \n apos;
&a \n pos;
```

I did the following regular expression, and it works in [RegexBuddy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RegexBuddy) (JGsoft flavor).

```
&(\r?\n?a)(\r?\n?p)(\r?\n?o)(\r?\n?s)(\r?\n?;)
```

I tried to translate that to the UltraEdit format

```
&^{^p^}^{a^}^{^p^}^{o^}^{^p^}^{s^}^{^p^}^{;^}
```

but it doesn't work.

The documentation of UltraEdit says:

```
^{A^}^{B^}  (A|B)   Matches expression A OR B
```

Reference http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/regular_expressions.html

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you saying that you have files where HTML identities are split across lines? For example, `&apos;` might be `&a⏎` followed by `pos;⏎` on the next line? `o.O` That is highly unusual. What produced such a (to be frank, broken) file?

Comment: you first question, yes. second question SQL Server generate xml schemas with FOR XML PATH in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that UltraEdit's single- and multi-line handling of regex is [spotty/non-standard](http://www.ultraedit.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=6042).

You could try setting the regex mode to `Perl` or `Unix` and using your original expression.

Also, if you copy-pasted your UE expression to the question instead of typing it manually and making a typo, then it is incorrect. You are checking for `&\na\no\ns\n;` instead of `&\na\np\no\ns\n;` (you forgot the literal *p*). It should be

```
&^{^p^}^{a^}^{^p^}^{p^}^{o^}^{^p^}^{s^}^{^p^}^{;^}
```

Comment: yes, i write wrong the expression.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you saying that you already tried the UE regex expression I included in my answer (with the `^pp`)? If you already tried that and it still did not work, then try changing the regex mode and use your original expression.